# How to work on a windows IDE while my Git repository is on Linux (using VMPlayer)

Tags: windows, linux, git, rubymine

I want to develop on 2 systems - using Linux (ubuntu) for server/git repo while having my IDE (RubyMine) in Win7. What is the best approach to configure my environment so the files will be shared between the systems, and also that my Win RubyMine will work correctly with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need git on Windows installed for starters. Then you can setup a shared directory that both Linux and Windows can use. In there you put your repo so that it can be accessed from both sides. Or you use dropbox and access it from both systems. Why don't you use Rubymine in Linux? Is it Win/Mac only?

Comment: No, there's a linux system, but I had performance issues due to the VMWare and I prefer using it on windows instead.

Anyway, as far as I know Git on windows handles whitespaces differently than in linux. Won't installing both version create problems?

Comment: actually if you work on a share you can have git installed in linux only and do all your versioning from there. After all both systems use the same repo, right?

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox for hosting and share the folder through the guest add ins. You don't want to switch to the vm while working. Terminal into the vm from windows.